# Convert query from mysql to sqlite3

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a very simple MySQL query

```
select clients.id as selected_id,(select clients.id 
from clients where clients.id=selected_id) 
from clients where clients.id=20
```

when I run it on MySQL, its runs fine. But on Sqlite3, the same query throws

> Error: no such column: selected_id

I tried Googling it, but most solutions are w.r.t. joins. Here I need it within the select part.

Comment: What is the problem with using JOINS?

Comment: you can't alias id as selected_id and use it in a subquery quite like that. You would need to alias the tables and join them on their id's.
This being said I don't understand the point in your query. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is a large query already built to run with MySQL. Now we are porting the same code to run with sqlite and we need to ensure that minimal changes are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite conforms to the SQL standard, which says that aliases in the SELECT clause are used only for output columns, but are not available in the clause itself.

The proper way to use a correlated subquery like this is to rename one of the tables:

```
SELECT id AS selected_id,
       (SELECT id 
        FROM clients AS c2       -- !
        where c2.id = clients.id
       ) AS the_other_id
FROM clients
WHERE id = 20
```